# Rails3 SOLR sort order using a child field

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, solr

I have a working search using SOLR in a Rails 3 app. My controller returns results in pubdate order. I am trying to sub-order by the Section.name. How can I add the child field to the order-by syntax?

Here is my code:

```
@stories = Story.search do
    paginate(:page => params[:page])
    order_by :pubdate, :desc
    order_by :section_id                <---want to suborder by Section.name
    fulltext params[:search_query]
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to add the section name to the parent field to be able to sort it using the Section name.
You can check on [Solr Join](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/Join) feature for any JIRA to enable sorting on the Child fields.

Documentation mentions :-

> For people who are used to SQL, it's important to note that Joins in
>   Solr are not really equivalent to SQL Joins because no information
>   about the table being joined "from" is carried forward into the final
>   result. A more appropriate SQL analogy would be an "inner query"